# cmake ignores -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug

Tags: c, cmake, ndebug

I'm just trying to build a cmake project in debug-mode to enable asserts. I tried the following versions:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -L ../../
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -L ../../
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -L ../../
```

Unfortunately none of theese has the desired effect - that `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is set to `Debug` (and therefore the `NDEBUG`-flag is not passed to gcc).

Additionally I added `variable_watch(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)` to my main `CMakeLists.txt` to check whether the value get's overridden somewhere. But the first output is a `READ_ACCESS` in my main 
Additionally I added `variable_watch(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)` to my main `CMakeLists.txt` and the value there already is `Release`.

Does someone have an idea why cmake ignores the configuration?

I'm using cmake version 2.8.7.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `CMakeCache.txt`?

Comment: Yes, there is set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` - and even changing this manually and then rerunning `cmake` has not effect (the value in `CMakeCache.txt` get's overwritten again).

Comment: Is it related to this? http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.kde.devel.general/46310

Comment: No, not really. My problem is not that the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` does not have the effect it should have but instead that I cannot set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to `Debug`..

Comment: I already cleaned the build directory and tried again which also did not have any effect. And: You're right. I'm using Unix-Makefiles.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820155.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok, `fgrep -R "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE"` finally found the problem for me. In some `CMakeLists.txt`-file I found something like that:

```
SET( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release ... FORCE )
```

That overrides every user defined parameters (because of the `FORCE`).

What works for me is that:

```
IF( NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE )
   SET( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release ... FORCE )
ENDIF()
```

Thank's for your hints!

Comment: Does it work for you? For me, using Ninja as the target of CMake, it doesn't seem to work. What version of CMake do you use?

Comment: On modern CMake (Say 3.10 and up) see [KitWare Blog - CMake and the Default Build Type](https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-and-the-default-build-type/).

Comment: What is the ... for? An ellipsis replaces text that was left out. Or is it a literal ...?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that there is something wrong with your config..

I wrote a complete, simple example here: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68798379/cmake-build-type.tar.bz2

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

project(playlib)

message("CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")

IF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
  message("Debug build.")
ELSEIF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Release)
  message("Release build.")
ELSE()
  message("Some other build type.")
ENDIF()

add_library(TESTLIB SHARED src/test.c)
```

When you execute cmake with

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../../
```

It gives the following output:

```
$ ./gen-linux.sh
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Debug
Debug build.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/wojci/stack-overflow/cmake-build-type/build/linux
```

It shows that CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is being set from the command line and it being recognized in the CMakeLists.txt config.

What happens when you run it on your system using your version of CMake?

Comment: what if someone make this `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG`?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
IF(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} MATCHES Debug)
...
ENDIF()
```