# how to build dependent shared libraries with debug symbols in cmake?

Tags: c++, debugging, cmake, makefile

My code is organized like this:

- cpp

  - main.cpp (calls code from `dataStructures/` and `common/`)
  - CMakeLists.txt (*topmost* CMakeLists file)
  - build
  - common

    - CMakeLists.txt (should be responsible for building common shared library)
    - include

      - utils.h
    - src

      - utils.cpp
    - build
  - dataStructures

    - CMakeLists.txt (build dataStructures shared library - dependent on common library)
    - include

      - dsLinkedList.h
    - src

      - dsLinkedList.cpp
    - build

`build\` directories contain the built target. The actual code can be seen here: https://github.com/brainydexter/PublicCode/tree/master/cpp

As of now, CMakeLists.txt in each of the subdirectories build their own shared libraries. Topmost CMakeLists file then references the libraries

I kick off cmake to spit make file with debug symbols like this:

> cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..

This only generates the main.cpp with debug symbols but doesn't propogate the build type to dependent shared libraries. How can I do that in cmake ?

I'm trying to do this on macosx.

When I run `make VERBOSE=1`, from the output it seems that cmake is generating shared library with debug symbols:

```
cd /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/common /Users/priyank/pj/repo/Publi
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build'
make -f common/CMakeFiles/cppCommon.dir/build.make common/CMakeFiles/cppCommon.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build'
[ 11%] Building CXX object common/CMakeFiles/cppCommon.dir/src/utils.cpp.o
cd /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build/common && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++   -DcppCommon_EXPORTS -g -fPIC -I/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/common/include  
[ 22%] Linking CXX shared library libcppCommon.dylib
cd /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build/common && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cppCommon.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++  -g -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  -o libcppCommon.dylib -install_name @rpath/libcppCommon.dylib CMakeFiles/cppCommon.dir/src/uti
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build'
[ 22%] Built target cppCommon


make -f dataStructures/CMakeFiles/cppDS.dir/build.make dataStructures/CMakeFiles/cppDS.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build'
cd /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/dataStructures /Users/priyank/pj/re
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build'
make -f dataStructures/CMakeFiles/cppDS.dir/build.make dataStructures/CMakeFiles/cppDS.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build'
[ 33%] Building CXX object dataStructures/CMakeFiles/cppDS.dir/src/dsBinarySearchTree.cpp.o
cd /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build/dataStructures && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++   -DcppDS_EXPORTS -g -fPIC -I/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/dataStructur
[ 44%] Building CXX object dataStructures/CMakeFiles/cppDS.dir/src/dsLinkedList.cpp.o
cd /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build/dataStructures && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++   -DcppDS_EXPORTS -g -fPIC -I/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/dataStructur
[ 55%] Linking CXX shared library libcppDS.dylib
cd /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build/dataStructures && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cppDS.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++  -g -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  -o libcppDS.dylib -install_name @rpath/libcppDS.dylib CMakeFiles/cppDS.dir/src/dsBinarySearchT
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build'
[ 55%] Built target cppDS


make -f test/dataStructures/CMakeFiles/testCppDS.dir/build.make test/dataStructures/CMakeFiles/testCppDS.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build'
cd /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/test/dataStructures /Users/priyank/
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build'
make -f test/dataStructures/CMakeFiles/testCppDS.dir/build.make test/dataStructures/CMakeFiles/testCppDS.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build'
[ 66%] Building CXX object test/dataStructures/CMakeFiles/testCppDS.dir/src/testDsLinkedList.cpp.o
cd /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build/test/dataStructures && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++   -DtestCppDS_EXPORTS -g -fPIC -I/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/tes
[ 77%] Linking CXX shared library libtestCppDS.dylib
cd /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build/test/dataStructures && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/testCppDS.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++  -g -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  -o libtestCppDS.dylib -install_name @rpath/libtestCppDS.dylib CMakeFiles/testCppDS.dir/src/tes
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build'
[ 77%] Built target testCppDS


make -f CMakeFiles/execCpp.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/execCpp.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build'
cd /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/c
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/execCpp.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/execCpp.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build'
[ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/execCpp.dir/main.cpp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -g -I/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/dataStructures/include -I/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/common/include -I/Users/priyank/pj/
[100%] Linking CXX executable execCpp
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/execCpp.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++   -g -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/execCpp.dir/main.cpp.o  -o execCpp  test/dataStructures/libtestCppDS.d
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build'
[100%] Built target execCpp
make[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build'
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/priyank/pj/repo/PublicCode/cpp/build/CMakeFiles 0
```

Comment: which build system/ compiler are you using?

Comment: @DenisBlank cmake is the build system. and im trying to be cross platform between macosx and windows. on macosx, cmake resolves compiler to `AppleClang` and creates `make` files

Comment: On Windows the build type can't be set through CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE as far as i know. You need to set the build type inside MSVC, then it will generate debug symbols for the shared libraries see: http://i.imgur.com/BAZKPrh.png

Comment: Weird, well, I use macosx as the primary platform. Do you know how to do this on macosx ?

Comment: I don't know it but i assume that it is like on Unix, the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is responsible for the overall build type, how do you know that the shared libraries aren't build with debug?

Comment: when I'm in gdb and I invoke functions that belong to shared library: gdb just skips over them and doesn't step inside those functions.

Comment: Is it possible that gdb doesn't find your debug symbols?

Comment: I suggest that you force the setting in all your `CMakeLists.txt` using something like `set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug ... FORCE )` (cf. [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907679/cmake-ignores-d-cmake-build-type-debug) (It's not what I would call a "clean" solution, but it might get the job done ;) ). Also, make sure that your `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` has the `-g` option (or whatever is the equivalent for your compiler).

Comment: But then how can I maintain different project runtime configurations ?

Comment: I met similar problem in Ubuntu.GDb sucks when try to step into some function in shared library when use b class::func.But it do works when using b file:line. And gdb works pretty well inside VS code IDE. I doubt there is no wrong with cmake and shared library, but some thing wrong in gdb.