# gdb set break in .so file, no source file named

Tags: c++, debugging, cmake, gdb, .so

I build a project witch `cmake`. I have one executable file, and serveral `.so` files generated after the `make`. The `.so` file is in dir `build/lib`, and the excutable file is in dir `build/bin`.

My project dir likes,

```
-main.cpp
-test.cpp
--cfd/cfd.cpp
```

`cfd.cpp` generate `cfd.so`, and finally it links to the executable file.

I can set breaks in some src files, such as `main.cpp`, `test.cpp` and so on, but I can not set breaks in the `.so` linked source file, like `cfd.cpp`.

I haved tried several methods, such as,

- set LD_LIBRARY_PATH( or ldconfig [.so dir])
- set solib-search-path

when I run gdb, the program can load the `.so` file. I use `info shared`, the output is as bellow.
[image]

but I can't set breaks at `cfd.cpp`. I use the command `b cfd.cpp:33`, the `33` line is a function which called in test.cpp. The gdb outputs the info as bellow,

```
No source file named cfd.cpp.   
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]
```

Can any one help me, thank you.

Comment: `libcdf_interrface` has `*` in the Read column. It means `(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.`. Can you confirm that your library has no debug info?

Comment: I set the cmake in debug mode, `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug"), set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "$ENV{CXXFLAGS} -pg -std=c++11 -fPIC ")`,  and set the library as `add_library(cfd_interface SHARED ${SRC})`.  The target_link_libraries is set in `general` mode. Maybe I missed some steps.

Comment: `-pg` is for profiling. For debug info just `-g`

Comment: Yes, I understand. But this would not affect the Debug process.

Comment: I would try `target_link_libraries` in `debug` mode.

Comment: Use `make VERBOSE=1` for reveal **actual command line** which is used for compile and link your library.

Comment: I found when compile to `.so`, the command  has no `-g ` option and other `.so` neither. But the `libgbk.so` can be read, the `libcfd_interface.so` can not .`/usr/bin/g++-7 -fPIC   -shared -Wl,-soname,libcfd_interface.so -o ../../../lib/libcfd_interface.so ...`

Comment: Add output of the `file` command for both of the libraries

Comment: I don't get it. What' your meaning of `add output of thr file command for the library`. How to do this, I am confusing.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't set breaks at cfd.cpp

This is because your `libcfd_interface.so` is compiled *without* debug info (that's what the little `(*}` next to it means, as GDB tells you at the end of `info shared` output).

The fix is to rebuild it with the `-g` flag.

> I found when compile to .so, the command has no -g option and other .so neither. But the libgbk.so can be read

You are mistaken. IF `libgbk.so` is *compiled* without `-g` flag, then you wouldn't be able to set breakpoints in it either.

Note that `-g` flag is requited when *compiling*, which is different from linking (you show *link* command for `libcfd_interface.so`, so you might be confusing the two).

Comment: I know the differnce between `compiling` and `linking` process. Maybe my problem is I don't know how to set the `shared liarary compiling` in debug mode. I looked the `cmake` command, but I couldn't find anything like this.

Comment: This issue is same to mine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225978/how-to-build-dependent-shared-libraries-with-debug-symbols-in-cmake