# Should I cache CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE?

Tags: cmake

If you don't set the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`, then, by default, it doesn't get cached. Should I cache it? e.g. should I have:

```
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release" )
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release" CACHE STRING "Type of build (Debug, Release etc." FORCE)
endif()
```

or just:

```
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release" )
endif()
```

Or does it not really matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` in CMake's Cache

The user would normally define [`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) via the command line with `cmake -D ...`. So this does generate a cached entry.

And even when you don't give a `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` for single configuration makefile generators, CMake will automatically [create an empty cache entry](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeCommonLanguageInclude.cmake#L23) (so the user can choose in e.g. `cmake-gui`):

```c
//Choose the type of build, options are: None(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or
// CMAKE_C_FLAGS used) Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel.
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=
```

If no default for `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is given by the CMake's Platform/Compiler definitions via `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_INIT` like for [`Windows-MSVC`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Platform/Windows-MSVC.cmake#L120):

```perl
# default to Debug builds
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_INIT Debug)
```

#### Settings a Default for `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`

So yes, if you want to force a default that is visible in the GUI then set the cached variable (see @Tsyvarev answer).

I don't normally force the cached defaults, I just set a temporary value if none is given. This allows e.g. my project to be used as a sub-project.

But that's more a matter of your personal taste.

In my project's those default `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` checks look a little more complex, since I allow more use cases:

```perl
# Make RelWithDebInfo the default (it does e.g. add '-O2 -g -DNDEBUG' for GNU)
#   If not in multi-configuration environments, no explicit build type 
#   is set by the user and if we are the root CMakeLists.txt file.
if (NOT CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES AND 
    NOT CMAKE_NO_BUILD_TYPE AND
    NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE AND
    CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)
endif()

if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    string(TOUPPER "_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" MY_PROJECT_BUILD_TYPE_EXT)
endif() 

# Choose a configuration for our compiler tests
if (NOT CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES AND 
    NOT CMAKE_NO_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_CONFIGURATION "${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
else()
    set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_CONFIGURATION RelWithDebInfo)
endif()
```

But probably I should update this code to take the new [`GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG.html) global property into account (instead of checking for `CMAKE_NO_BUILD_TYPE`).

#### References

- ["CMake and the Default Build Type"](https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-and-the-default-build-type/) blog post by [Marcus D. Hanwell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143086/marcus-d-hanwell)
- [CMake Issue #16768: Add reliable way to detect multi-config generators](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16768)

Comment: I'm actually not quite following, especially w.r.t. sub-projects and the com "compile configuration vs the "build type".

Comment: @einpoklum If my project is used as a sub-project via `add_subdirectory()` it should not set/force global properties. So if your parent project doesn't give a default, you shouldn't either. But I as said this is more a matter of taste and the important part here is the `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` check.

Answer (score 7):

Caching of *CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE* is usefull for cmake-gui: user of your project would able to change a build type in a nice manner.

There is a good template for setting default *CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE* [from Kitware](https://www.kitware.com/cmake-and-the-default-build-type/):

```
# Set a default build type if none was specified
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE AND NOT CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
  message(STATUS "Setting build type to 'Debug' as none was specified.")
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build." FORCE)
  # Set the possible values of build type for cmake-gui
  set_property(CACHE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE PROPERTY STRINGS "Debug" "Release"
    "MinSizeRel" "RelWithDebInfo")
endif()
```

Comment: If there are 'configuration types', why would there not be a 'build type'?

Comment: Having `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` variable defined means that built tool is *multiconfiguration* - it can configure several build types *at once*. For such tool (e.g. Visual Studio) concrete build type isn't known at configuration time, so `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable is meaningless.