# How do I limit the cmake configuration types for Visual Studio builds from command line?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I am trying to set the configuration types for my CMakeLists.txt from the command line using the following call:

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -T host=x64 -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES:STRING=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Temp -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\Temp\downloads
```

But unfortunately it seems to be not recognized and configure step (try_compile) is done with Debug as default configuration.

I read the docs for `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` variable, searched the net but found no solution so far.
What am I doing wrong or is it a known limitation?

Environment: CMake 3.11.0, Visual Studio 14 2015 (x86/x64), Visual Studio 15 2017 (x86/x64) Windows 10, Windows 7

Comment: What do you mean with "configure step is done with Debug as default coniguration"? Probably you need to set [`CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_CONFIGURATION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_CONFIGURATION.html) also.

Comment: That seems to be exactly the issue. I was not aware of this variable. If you make that an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reduce the `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` to a single configuration, you probably need to also set [`CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_CONFIGURATION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_CONFIGURATION.html):

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" 
         -T host=x64 
         -D CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES:STRING=Release 
         -D CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_CONFIGURATION:STRING=Release 
         -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Temp 
         -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\Temp\downloads
```

**References**

- [Cmake generators for Visual Studio do not set CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661264/cmake-generators-for-visual-studio-do-not-set-cmake-configuration-types)
- [Should I cache CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820155/should-i-cache-cmake-build-type)